# Get Backgrundcolor of Element on a position with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, background-color

I try to identify the color of a specific element on a position (sometimes its inside an Iframe)

```
var el = document.elementFromPoint(1000, 10);
if (el instanceof HTMLIFrameElement)
    el = el.contentWindow.document.elementFromPoint(1000, 10);
```

el returns:

```
<div class="container-fluid"</div>
```

This element itself has no styling, so `el.style.backgroundColor` gives me ""

The element which contains the information about the styling is the parent div, but since the website is dynamic, this is also not always the case.

Is there a workaround or shortcut to get receive the color of the current position on the body for example?

Something like `document.getColorFromPoint(1000, 10)` which would return a hex code or rgba value?

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

`window.getComputedStyles` is what you want to use since `el.style` property return only *inline* styles applied to the element.

I would approach it this way:

- Find the current element with `elementFromPoint` method
- Get the background with `window.getComputedStyle(element)["backgroundColor"]`
- If it returns empty string for current element, call the same method on its parent `window.getComputedStyle(element)["backgroundColor"]`

  - Run this until you get the background color!